# Deleting the last column in a python array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to build a basic number classifier in python, and I have a 3923 * 65 array. Each row in my array is an image that when showed is a number from 0 to 9. 3923 * 64 is the actual size of my array, and the last column is the actual number the image is. I already have an array for the entire 3923 * 65, and one for the 3923 * 64 part of it.
full array:

```
fullImageArray = np.zeros((len(myImageList),65), dtype = np.float64)
fullImageArray = np.array(myImageList)
```

number array:

```
fullPlotArray = np.zeros((len(myImageList),64), dtype = np.float64)
fullPlotArray = np.array(fullImageArray)
fullPlotArray.resize(len(myImageList),64)
```

How do I make an array of only the last column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create views of your data by slicing the array:

```
full_array = np.array(myImageList)
plot_array = full_array[:, :64]  # First 64 columns of full_array
last_column = full_array[:, -1]
```

The results will be views into the same data as the original array; no copy is created.  changing the last column of `full_array` is the same as changing `last_column`, since they are pointing to the same data in memory.

See the [Numpy documentation on indexing and slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) for further information.