# how to remove last column of an array in python

Tags: python, numpy

My array size is unknown and I would like to remove the very last column

```
a = np.array([["A1","A2","A3"],["B1","B2","B3"],["C1","C2","C3"]])
```

I have tried

```
a[-1:]
```

but it deleted all rows except the last row

I also tried

```
a[:-1]
```

and it deleted the last row.

How can I delete the last column?

Comment: the last column means `"A3", "B3", "C3"` right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove one column for a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710684/remove-one-column-for-a-numpy-array)

Comment: Also a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397580/deleting-the-last-column-in-a-python-array

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest you to read the docs about [Basic Slicing and Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) the `numpy` array.

**Try this:**

```
arr = a[:, :-1] #--> first two columns of array
```

**Note 1:**
The resulting array `arr` of the slicing operation is just a view inside the original array `a`, no copy is created. If you change any entity inside the `arr`, this change will also be propagated in the array `a` and vice-a-versa.

For Example, 
*Changing the value of `arr[0, 0]` will also change the corresponding value of `a[0, 0]`.*

---

**Note 2:** If you want to create a new array, while removing the last column so that changes in one array **should not be propagated** in other array, you can use [`numpy.delete`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) which *returns a new array with sub-arrays along an axis deleted.*

```
arr = np.delete(a, -1, axis=1) # --> returns new array
```

---

**Output of `>>> arr`:**

```
[['A1' 'A2']
 ['B1' 'B2']
 ['C1' 'C2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([["A1","A2","A3"],["B1","B2","B3"],["C1","C2","C3"]])
print(a)

b = np.delete(a, np.s_[-1:], axis=1)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[['A1' 'A2' 'A3']
 ['B1' 'B2' 'B3']
 ['C1' 'C2' 'C3']]

[['A1' 'A2']
 ['B1' 'B2']
 ['C1' 'C2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to delete the last column

```
b = a[:,:2]
'''array([['A1', 'A2'],
   ['B1', 'B2'],
   ['C1', 'C2']], dtype='<U2')'''
```

if you wish to delete the last row

```
c = a[:2]
'''array([['A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
   ['B1', 'B2', 'B3']], dtype='<U2'''
```